# How to calculate the percentages of 1 variable using other variable in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like below and i want to calculate the percentage's of frequency by state.

data

```
#    State     Ideology Freq
#1    CO Conservative   33
#2    CO  Independent   17
#3    CO      Liberal   50
#4    DC Conservative   33
#5    DC  Independent   33
#6    DC      Liberal   33
```

Expected output:

```
 #    State     Ideology Freq percentage
 #1    CO Conservative   33   33%
 #2    CO  Independent   17   17%
 #3    CO      Liberal   50   50%
 #4    DC Conservative   33   33.33%
 #5    DC  Independent   33   33.33%
 #6    DC      Liberal   33   33.33%
```

Tried:

```
data$percentage = data$Freq/sum(data$Freq)  
percent <- function(x, digits = 2, format = "f", ...) {  
 paste0(formatC(100 * x, format = format, digits = digits, ...), "%")  
}  
data$percentage = percent(data$percentage)
```

I am able to calculate the percentages by overall level but i want to calculate the percentages by freqvalue/sum(freq values of state).

Comment: Your `Freq` column is already the percentage here, no? Just `paste0(df$Freq, "%")` already gives you your column...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- group_by(data, State) %>%
        mutate(percentage = paste0(round(Freq/sum(Freq) * 100, 2), "%"))
data
## Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
## Groups: State [2]
## 
##    State     Ideology  Freq percentage
##   (fctr)       (fctr) (int)      (chr)
## 1     CO Conservative    33        33%
## 2     CO  Independent    17        17%
## 3     CO      Liberal    50        50%
## 4     DC Conservative    33     33.33%
## 5     DC  Independent    33     33.33%
## 6     DC      Liberal    33     33.33%
```

The first line groups the data by `State`. All the operations in the following `mutate()` are evaluated for each group. Therefore, `sum(Freq)` sums up the value of `Freq` per state.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
groups <- group_by(data, State)
summary <- summarize( SUM.OF.STATE = sum(State ,na.rm = TRUE))
DF.YOU.WANT <- merge(data, summary, by.x = "State", by.y = "State")
# and now just divide columnt with freq by columnn from summary df with sum of freq.data is your data frame.
```